# How to parse [REDACTED] of a key vault value into json string in Azure Notebook

Tags: json, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-keyvault

I am trying to access 2 values from Azure key vault. But it is not getting parsed correctly.

I am expected the hdr value as

```
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_id': '890fy6', 'client_secret': '765r4'}
```

Below is my code

> clientID_KV = dbutils.secrets.get(scope =
> 'My-Scopes-{}'.format(env_name), key = 'CID') clientSecret_KV =
> dbutils.secrets.get(scope = 'My-Scopes-{}'.format(env_name), key =
> 'CS')
>
> hdr = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'client_id' : clientID_KV
> , 'client_secret' : clientSecret_KV} print(hdr)

Output

> {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_id': '[REDACTED]',
> 'client_secret': '[REDACTED]'}

But I am able to get the values printed using

> displayHTML("".join(clientID_KV))
> displayHTML("".join(clientSecret_KV))

but not through json.

Could someone please help here.

Comment: Why do you want to expose the key vault values? The whole idea behind this is to mask all the secrets like access keys, SAS urls, tokens, etc. For your downstream applications to work to you can pass the values as it is. If you really need to fetch the values, one work around I found is passing the values from master notebook to child notebooks using notebook parameters. See if that helps!

Comment: Exactly. I agree.I have to pass these values to a request url - hdr is one of the parameters and it is not able to get the response from api as it is not able to parse redacted value

Comment: In that case, one solution I see is to pass the values from master to child notebook using notebook parameters.

Comment: Yeah sure..let me check in that way

Answer (score 4):

My solution can be seen as followed.

strA = clientID_KV[0:len(clientID_KV)-1]

strB = clientID_KV[len(clientID_KV)-1:]

clientID = strA + ":)" + strB # ":)"can be replaced by other characters

The consumers of your json should realize that ":)" must be removed.

[image]